# ts-node-dev runs into an error: "Cannot find module 'typescript'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, npx, ts-node-dev

I am trying to set up a basic nest.js app.

main.js is in the src folder. I run this command:

```
  npx ts-node-dev src/main.ts
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- /home/yilmaz/.npm/_npx/429895/lib/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/index.js
- /home/yilmaz/.npm/_npx/429895/lib/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/bin.js
```

I installed typescript globally, close the terminal and restart it. run `tsc -v` and I get "Version 4.3.5" but the error is not resolved.

This is the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

After I installed typescript, I recreated this file with `tsc --init`
and enabled

```
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
```

Comment: maybe you can try `npm link typescript`?

Comment: @Yilmaz Are you using node 12 or 14? i encounter this error on those versions before. The solution of mine is either 1) upgrade to `node.js 16` or  2) install and run both ts and ts-node-dev on the fly  `npx -p typescript -p ts-node-dev ts-node-dev src/main.ts`

Comment: `npx -p typescript -p ts-node-dev ts-node-dev src/main.ts` worked me, after installing `rxjs`.

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem myself and even tough I didn't clearly understand the main cause, I did the following stuff and it worked out.

So basically I have installed the `ts-node-dev` package as a dev dependency(`npm i --save-dev ts-node-dev`), and after that was running into another error regarding  `rxjs`, so I just installed that too as a dependency(`npm i rxjs`) and after that it worked `ts-node-dev` as well as `npx ts-node-dev`